# creating a slideshow with variable length display of slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Trying to create a slideshow with slides.js jquery plugin.

What I want is for the first slide (which has a video on embedded in it) to display for 7seconds and for the rest of the slides to each display for 4 seconds.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
  $(function(){
      $('#slides').slides({
          preload: true,
          generateNextPrev: false,
          play: function(){
              if($('#slides').childNodes[2].css('display', 'block')){
                   return 7000;
              } else {
                   return 4000;
              } 
          }
      });
      $("#menu select").change(function() {
          window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
      });
  });
```

At first I thought this function ran every time the slides changed. I realize now that this anon function runs once and is done. which means it doesn't come back to see if that slide is not `display: block;` or `display: none;`. Which leaves me wondering what to do.

I checked the documentation on the slides.js page but didn't see anything that stood out as being able to help.

TLDC: Is it possible to have variable lengths of display time using slides.js? And if its not what can I use?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be possible *easily* using slides.js, so let me introduce my own jQuery slider called [**Do It Yourself Slider**](http://pioul.fr/jquery-diyslider/).

> This plugin is a foundation on which you’ll build a slider yourself,
>   one that really fits your needs.

Thus it's possible to do whatever you want to do, because you have to do it yourself: you're not limited by the plugin.

Have a look at the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/gk5Wx/1/) I made for what you're asking, a first slide that lasts 7 seconds while the others last 4.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this personally, so apologies if I'm off base.

Looking through [here](http://slidesjs.com/), looks like the `play` function is the "go" button and `pause` stops it. What you need is something that runs on every animation, not just the initial `play` event. Try `animationStart` instead.

```
  $('#slides').slides({
      preload: true,
      generateNextPrev: false,
      play: 7000,
      animationStart: function(){
          if($('#slides').childNodes[2].css('display', 'block')){
               $("#slides").slides({ slideSpeed: 7000 });
          } else {
               $("#slides").slides({ slideSpeed: 4000 });
          } 
      }
```

Not sure if it runs immediately prior to the animation (would work perfect then) or immediately after animation starts. If it's after, try using `animationComplete` and set the time based on the next slide.

Again, I'm just taking kindof a blind stab at this, how's it look?